# Can FIGNORE be limited to specific applications?

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, inputrc

I know that you can use [FIGNORE](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables) to remove filename completion from suffixes.

For example, to avoid a lot of garbage files produced by LaTeX, I've been using:

```
FIGNORE=bst:aux:bbl:blg:pdf:fls:fdb_latexmk
```

However, I would really prefer to apply this FIGNORE *only* when using specific command line applications (in particular `vim` or `nvim`). That way, I would get full filename completion normally, and limit it only "on demand".

I've experimented a little with [`$if`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Init-Constructs) blocks in my `~/.inputrc` file but without any luck.

Comment: Did you try something like `alias fvim='FIGNORE=bst:aux:bbl:blg:pdf:fls:fdb_latexmk vim'`?

Comment: @romainl Just tried. It doesn't appear to work. `FIGNORE` may need to be set in the shell rather than used per command in that way. (Hadn't thought to do it that way - a good thought, but looks like it doesn't work.)